# AndroidThings not working on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: android, macos, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Im trying to get any version of android running on my Raspberry Pie 3 B. Ive followed the [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) and used these build settings

- OEM partition size: 512MB
- Using google play services
- empty bundle
- OS build: OIR1.170720.017

Im able to successfully flash the image onto a 64gb micro sd (with etcher) card but when I insert it into the Pi and power it on I see a rainbow screen flash a couple times and then it goes completely black. I have tried all OS builds and none of them work.

Another weird thing is once the flash of the sd card is complete my Mac is unable to read it and presents a pop up asking to initialize it. This is strange to me because when I have the stock raspberry by OS flashed on the sd card my Mac is able to display the filesystem.

Comment: Might want to ask at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you try another SD card perhaps? I ran into an unusual issue where the SD card was having issues.

Also, another issue I had once was when my OEM size was too big. Maybe you can reduce it to 128MB and see if there's still issues.

The RPi does have some issues with some HDMI displays in DP5. Can you confirm by trying to use `adb`?

Comment: Ive tried with a smaller OEM size and doesnt work. I also tried adb and nothing was on the network. Ive been able to get android 6 and 7 running with the SD card by youtubing "Android Raspberry Pie" and using the img files provided in the videos. Although with these builds i have not had play store or been able to install any play store apps. Using the img files provided by youtube videos also keep the SD card in a readable format. It seems Android Things doesnt provide a valid build image...

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy SD card to me, from your description you've written and re-written it a lot. I would try another card. (I get the same pop up on Mac for a legit flashed sd card)